# How to parse HTML content of a variable in Angular.JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, ng-bind-html

I am new to Angular.JS & are currently working on my first project. I have a page full of entries of the kind

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Teaser</p>
<p>(a link)</p>
```

The teaser *may* include HTML formating or elements like the `&amp;`. What I want to do is to "parse" this Teaser so that the formating is "understood" properly by the browser (currently Google Chrome).

For the detail page, an id is passed to the shownews, but the first call is without an id to read all the news from where, the user can reach the detail page by each news link. Here, I already head the same problem. Below, you see the Angular.JS code for both the main news page and the detail page, where I could solve the problem for the detail page by using the `ng-bind-html` directive as follows:

```js
 $scope.shownews = function(id) {

   if (typeof id === 'undefined') {
     $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'http://dev.ivm.at/getallnews.php'
     }).
       success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.allnews = data;
         $scope.myHTML = [];

         for (var i = 0; i < $scope.allnews.length; i++) {
           $scope.myHTML[i] = $scope.allnews[i].Teaser;
         }
       });
   } else {
     $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'http://dev.ivm.at/getnews.php?ID=' + id
     }).
       success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.singlenews = data;
         $scope.Newstitel = $scope.singlenews[0].Title
            //[...]
         $scope.Inhalt = $scope.singlenews[0].Inhalt;
         //[...]
         $scope.myHTML = "<h1>" + $scope.Newstitel + "</h1><br>" + $scope.Inhalt;
       });
   }
 }
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="allnews">
  <div id="sub">
    <section class="blog">
      <article ng-bind-html="myHTML" ng-repeat="news in allnews">
        <h1>{{news.Title}}</h1>
        <p>{{myHTML[$index]}}</p>
        <p class="readmore">
          <a href="onenews" ng-click="shownews(news.ID)">
                  Weiterlesen: {{news.Title}}
          </a>
          <span class="readmore_icon"></span>
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is how to use the `ng-bind-html` command properly so that it does parse the `$scope.myHTML` in the case it is an array of texts.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: instead of parsing array, just give require field to the ng-bind-html.  example:<p ng-bind-html="">

Comment: How can I do that? I do not know the number of news that are on the main page. Each news has a teaser. In the case of detail page with the only news, this is not a problem. I create the `$scope.myHTML`, which is a string in this case and not an array, inside the controller (see above).

Answer (score 4):

To do this you need to use `$sce`angularjs built-in service to secure the HTML content before parsing.

**Example**

HTML View:

```
<span ng-bind-html="toTrustedHTML(html)">
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.toTrustedHTML = function (html) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
  };
});
```

**UPDATE:**

You might need to use ngSantize and also check the following [URL](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#show-me-an-example-using-sce-) which contain a plunker explains that you need `$sce.trustAsHtml()` method.

Comment: Oh, the trust is not my current concern. What I need is text inside the array variable `$scope=myHTML[]` being formatted properly. I still do have the ampersand written as `&amp;`. Actually, I already have the solution for the single news _without_ securing it, and it works.

Comment: @Sae1962: you may need to check the current update I just added to the answer

Comment: Thank you! I changed following lines: `var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngSanitize']);`, `app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http, $sce) {...`, and `$scope.toTrustedHTML = function (html) { return $sce.trustAsHtml(html); }`, but get the error message `Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce (angular.js:5601)`. In the HTML file, I added also `<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>` after the line with `<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>`. What do you think causes the error?

Comment: Forgotten changes in HTML file: `<span ng-bind-html="toTrustedHTML(html)">` before `<article ng-repeat="news in allnews">` & the closing `</span>`.

Comment: Why do you need this part `myHTML[$index]`? Also, you are including angular-sanitize twice!! try it only once (either minified or full version)

Comment: Thank you for the double insertion warning! Concering the `myHTML[$index]`, this is the way I need it – perhaps, the syntax is not correct, but I need to access every single element of the myHTML array. Each of it contains the information that _may_ or may not include HTML tags. So, all of them have to be parsed.